# How to extract the port number from a listen address

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'd like to extract the port number from an address string. The whole string looks like this:

```
connect single-cluster --listen-addr=127.0.0.1:12345 --filename=hello
```

or

```
connect single-cluster --listen-addr=127.0.0.1 --filename=hello
```

I'd like to save the address and port from the `listen-addr` to two variables: `ADDR` and `PORT`. If the port does not exist in the input string, just leave the `PORT` variable empty, and set the `ADDR`.

Now if the port number exists in the input string, I can use this regex:

```
ORI_STR="connect single-cluster --listen-addr=127.0.0.1:12345 --filename=hello"

LISTEN_ADDR_REGEX="(^|[[:space:]])--listen-addr=(([^[:space:]]+):([^[:space:]]+))($|[[:space:]])"

[[ $ORI_STR =~ $LISTEN_ADDR_REGEX ]] && ADDR=${BASH_REMATCH[3]} && PORT=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}

echo "ADDR=$ADDR"
echo "PORT=$PORT"
```

This gives me:

```
ADDR=127.0.0.1
PORT=12345
```

But I don't know how to include the case that the port number is not set in the original string. (i.e. there's no `:12345` in the `ORI_STR`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `?` means zero or one match.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#ori_str="connect single-cluster --listen-addr=127.0.0.1:12345 --filename=hello"

ori_str="connect single-cluster --listen-addr=127.0.0.1 --filename=hello"

listen_addr_regex="^.* --listen-addr=([^:]+)(:)?([^[:space:]]+)? .*$"

[[ $ori_str =~ $listen_addr_regex ]] && addr=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} && port=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

echo "addr=$addr"
echo "port=$port"
```

---

- Use `"${port:-none}"` to use `none` as the default value or change `none` to something else if needed

Answer (score 1):

This works with or without the port:

```
LISTEN_ADDR_REGEX="(^|[[:space:]])--listen-addr=(([^[:space:]:]+)(:([^[:space:]]+))?)($|[[:space:]])"
#                                                            ^   ^                ^^

[[ $ORI_STR =~ $LISTEN_ADDR_REGEX ]] && ADDR=${BASH_REMATCH[3]} && PORT=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
#                                                                                      ^

echo "ADDR=$ADDR"
echo "PORT=$PORT"
```

I added parentheses around the `:port` part and marked it optional with `?`. That moved the port from match group `4` to `5`. I also added `:` to the exclusion list for the IP address; without that the IP was greedily matching the port.

It's kind of hard to spot the differences so I marked them with `^` carets.